# Show parameter details of sql query when an error occurs

Tags: spring-boot, logging, jdbctemplate

I'm using a spring boot 1.5 java application and have set the log levels so that JDBC (using spring's jdbctemplate) sql queries and their parameters get logged. The database we connect to is Sybase v15.

```
logging:
  file: /app/logs/${spring.application.name}.log
  max-history: 10
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.springframework.jdbc: DEBUG
```

However, we noticed that when an exception occurs, the detailed parameter logs (showing which parameter gets bound to which value) entries are not shown, and instead we get the exception messageplus the stacktrace. This makes it difficult to know exactly which field is causing problems. Eg, the following message really requires parameter info to understand what is causing the issue:

```
UserRepositoryClient#updateUser(Long,User); content:
{"timestamp":"2019-01-17T09:05:18Z","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException","message":"PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?,     ?)]; Scale error during implicit conversion of DECIMAL value '0.1' to a INT field.\n; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Scale error during implicit conversion of DECIMAL value '0.1' to a INT field.\n","path":"/quotes/94379095"}
```

What loglevels or settings can we edit to show the parameter bind information, even when an error occurs during query execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct log levels we found are:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate: DEBUG #log sql queries
org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils: TRACE #Log sql parameter values
```